# Flip a Y coordinate within a min-max range

Tags: python, math, charts

I'm calculating a Y coordinate which represents a value on a y-axis on a chart I'm drawing in PIL, to display on an LCD display.

I set a `start_y` and an `end_y`. The (physical) top of the screen is `y = 0`. I get my y coordinate as follows:

```py
start_y = 10 # 10 pixels from top of screen
end_y = 60 # 60 pixels from top of screen
min = 10
max = 25
percentage_within_range = (value - min) / (max - min)
y = (percentage_within_range * (end_y - start_y)) + start_y
```

But the y coordinate I get is the 'wrong way around'. I.e. if the value was `19`, the resultant `y` would be `40`. That's 20 pixels from the *bottom* of the chart's display area, but I want it to be 20 pixels from the *top* of the chart's display area.

How do I reframe my calculation to return my y value 'reversed'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of the nature of the equation, it will give the value of the total pixels from the top of the chart as your `min max` and `start end` also start from the top. If you want the remaining pixels, You will have to subtract the current answer from the highest pixel possible which is `end_y`. Your equation will become

```
y = end_y - ((percentage_within_range * (end_y - start_y)) + start_y)
```

as far as my understanding of the question, I came upon this answer.